# Show the missing character in email validation using jquery validator plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there any property or any method that will return the missing character in jQuery validator plugin? I have a input field with id `uEmail`. I want to apply require and email validation using the jQuery validator plugin. In this input field I am entering the input as "abc.test". Then I have to show the error message as "Please enter a valid email address - this seems to be missing an @ sign.".

```
var test = jQuery('form').validate({

        rules:{
            uEmail:{
                email: true,
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            uEmail:{
                email:"Please enter a valid email address",
                required: "This field is required"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(element. error){
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Custom Method For Validation for email validate [Please Check](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)